# Convert PyTorch AutoTokenizer to TensorFlow TextVectorization

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tokenize, converters

I have a PyTorch encoder loaded on my PC with transformers.

I saved it in JSON with `tokenizer.save_pretrained(...)` and now I need to load it on another PC with TensorFlow TextVectorization as I don't have access to the transformers library.

How can I convert ? I read about the `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer_from_json` but it does not work.

In PyTorch JSON I have :

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "truncation": null,
  "padding": null,
  "added_tokens": [...],
  "normalizer": {...},
  "pre_tokenizer": {...},
  "post_processor": {...},
  "decoder": {...},
  "model": {...}
}
```

and TensorFlow is expecting, with TextVectorizer :

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        max_tokens=None,
        standardize="lower_and_strip_punctuation",
        split="whitespace",
        ngrams=None,
        output_mode="int",
        output_sequence_length=None,
        pad_to_max_tokens=False,
        vocabulary=None,
        idf_weights=None,
        sparse=False,
        ragged=False,
        **kwargs,
    ):
```

or with the tokenizer_from_json these kind of fields :

```
    config = tokenizer_config.get("config")

    word_counts = json.loads(config.pop("word_counts"))
    word_docs = json.loads(config.pop("word_docs"))
    index_docs = json.loads(config.pop("index_docs"))
    # Integer indexing gets converted to strings with json.dumps()
    index_docs = {int(k): v for k, v in index_docs.items()}
    index_word = json.loads(config.pop("index_word"))
    index_word = {int(k): v for k, v in index_word.items()}
    word_index = json.loads(config.pop("word_index"))

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(**config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply "tf.keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer_from_json.()" but you may need to correct format in JSON.

Sample: The sample they using " I love cats " -> " Sticky "

```
import tensorflow as tf

text = "I love cats"
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=10000, oov_token='<oov>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text])

# input
vocab = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "I", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_" ]
data = tf.constant([["_", "_", "_", "I"], ["l", "o", "v", "e"], ["c", "a", "t", "s"]])

layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
sequences_mapping_string = layer(data)
sequences_mapping_string = tf.constant( sequences_mapping_string, shape=(1,12) )
print( 'result: ' + str( sequences_mapping_string ) )

print( 'tokenizer.to_json(): ' + str( tokenizer.to_json() ) )

new_tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer_from_json(tokenizer.to_json())
print( 'new_tokenizer.to_json(): ' + str( new_tokenizer.to_json() ) )
```

Output:

```
result: tf.Tensor([[27 27 27  9 12 15 22  5  3  1 20 19]], shape=(1, 12), dtype=int64)
tokenizer.to_json(): {"class_name": "Tokenizer", "config": {"num_words": 10000, "filters": "!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n", "lower": true, "split": " ", "char_level": false, "oov_token": "<oov>", "document_count": 1, "word_counts": "{\"i\": 1, \"love\": 1, \"cats\": 1}", "word_docs": "{\"cats\": 1, \"love\": 1, \"i\": 1}", "index_docs": "{\"4\": 1, \"3\": 1, \"2\": 1}", "index_word": "{\"1\": \"<oov>\", \"2\": \"i\", \"3\": \"love\", \"4\": \"cats\"}", "word_index": "{\"<oov>\": 1, \"i\": 2, \"love\": 3, \"cats\": 4}"}}
new_tokenizer.to_json(): {"class_name": "Tokenizer", "config": {"num_words": 10000, "filters": "!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n", "lower": true, "split": " ", "char_level": false, "oov_token": "<oov>", "document_count": 1, "word_counts": "{\"i\": 1, \"love\": 1, \"cats\": 1}", "word_docs": "{\"cats\": 1, \"love\": 1, \"i\": 1}", "index_docs": "{\"4\": 1, \"3\": 1, \"2\": 1}", "index_word": "{\"1\": \"<oov>\", \"2\": \"i\", \"3\": \"love\", \"4\": \"cats\"}", "word_index": "{\"<oov>\": 1, \"i\": 2, \"love\": 3, \"cats\": 4}"}}
```

Comment: when saving a TF tokenizer there is no problem, this is when I want to load (convert) a PyTorch tokenizer that it does not work. Looking at the fields of your tokenizer.to_json() there a lot of differences I wouldn't know how to overcome, like "filters", "vocabulary", etc... ```{
  "class_name": "Tokenizer", 
  "config": {
    "num_words": 10000, 
    "filters": "!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n", 
    "lower": true, 
    "split": " ", ...```